# postgres - pg_stat_statements directory

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

Does pg_stat_statements use the same `stats_temp_directory` directory? Our `stats_temp_directory` is under `/var/run/postgresql` which resides in `tmps`. We have about 500 databases in an instance and set `pg_stat_statements.max` to `10000000` (20000 statements / db).

We don't want pg_stat_statements to be a major factor of i/o (we execute tons of short running queries). Can't seems to find this info in the [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgstatstatements.html).

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                                     version                                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.6.10-1.pgdg16.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pg_stat_statements always uses the literal directory "pg_stat_tmp", even if the "stats_temp_directory" parameter has been changed to point elsewhere.

See this note from the source code:

> Location of external query text file.  We don't keep it in the core
>    system's stats_temp_directory.  The core system can safely use that GUC
>    setting, because the statistics collector temp file paths are set only once
>    as part of changing the GUC, but pg_stat_statements has no way of avoiding
>    race conditions.  Besides, we only expect modest, infrequent I/O for query
>    strings, so placing the file on a faster filesystem is not compelling.

Are your tons of short-running queries all entirely different queries?  If they all normalize to a smaller set of queries (i.e. groups that differ only in supplied parameter values, not in SQL syntax elements or SQL identifiers) then they won't generate IO because pg_stat_statements only needs to update the in-memory counters, not the on-disk normalized query text.

Answer (score 1):

pg_stat_statements is keeping the whole **pg_stat_statements.max** in memory . So please check if you have enough memory for this. All memory is allocated at start , even if you don't need all. When the postgres server stops , all statistics will be saved to disk if you activate this , check  **pg_stat_statements.save** in postgresql.conf .

So , good news , no IO load :)  Again, please check available memory.

Comment: Your answer is only accurate up to version 9.3.  After that, while the statistics themselves are saved in memory, the text of the queries to which those stats apply are saved in files.

Comment: Yes, you are right! The statistics statements are saved by default in pg_stat_tmp folder and the size of the statement is limited track_activity_query_size  by default to 1024 Bytes. A statement is saved only once. In case the statements have binds all ok, otherwise if a lot is hardcoded inside the statement, then this folder could grow a lot. Please monitor it. Usually based on practice this should be less than 100MB and low IO activity

Comment: pg_stat_statements applies query normalization (since 9.2), so even if parameters are hard-coded into the SQL the client sends the query, they will be stripped back out again.  (which is nice overall, but can be a pain when one particular parameter value causes bad performance)